# Set icons to JFXButton

Tags: javafx

How to add an `icon` or a `fontawesome icon` to a `JFXButton` from the controller class?

```
public void initialize() {
    JFXButton hamburger = new JFXButton();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending @Mayur Patel answer, use JFXButton constructor with text and graphic, see documentation [JFXButton](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/src/main/java/com/jfoenix/controls/JFXButton.java):

```
public JFXButton(String text, Node graphic) {
    super(text, graphic);
    initialize();
}
```

So in your case, it should look like this:

```
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon.png"));
JFXButton hamburger = new JFXButton("Try me",image);
```

And with fontawesome icons (remember to import it first in your scene builder, if you are working with scene builder):

```
 <JFXButton fx:id="delete_btn" text="Try me">
   <graphic>
     <FontAwesomeIconView fill="WHITE" glyphName="play" size="16.0"/>
   </graphic>
 </JFXButton>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it might work -

```
JFXButton hamburger = new JFXButton();
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon.png"));
hamburger.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
```